# How do I create two new variables out of one variable, and attach dummy values to it in R?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am completely new to any kind of coding, nevermind R in particular, so my days of googling have not been very helpful. I would really appreciate any kind of help/insights!

I would like to know how to get two new variables out of the original variable, and attach new values to it - basically I start with this:

[image: starting point]

and want to obtain this:

[image: desired result]

I managed to get it in long format with `melt(dataname, id.vars=c("ID"))` and the ID & value I get are good. But there is only one variable with my four headers (loudHot, quietHot, loudCold, quietCold) repeated - how do I create two new variables out of this and assign the values to it (e.g. that "Volume" has the value 1 when the original variable is loudHot or loudCold and 0 if its quietHot or quietCold, and then "Temp" is 1 when the original variable is loudHot or quietHot and 0 when its loudCold or quietCold)?

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it - especially as I didn’t give you the data properly (thank you for making me aware in that regard too), so thanks for taking the extra steps!

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't be too hard on yourself - this isn't really trivial. Anyway, you can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` and some data manipulation with `dplyr` to achieve your desired outcome:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  mutate(Volume = as.numeric(grepl("loud", name)),
         Temp   = as.numeric(grepl("Hot",  name))) %>%
  select(ID, Volume, Temp, value)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 4
#>       ID Volume  Temp value
#>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     2      1     1    14
#>  2     2      0     1    16
#>  3     2      1     0    16
#>  4     2      0     0    15
#>  5     4      1     1    19
#>  6     4      0     1    15
#>  7     4      1     0    10
#>  8     4      0     0     8
#>  9     6      1     1    11
#> 10     6      0     1    17
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(ID        = (1:8) * 2,
                 loudHot   = c(14, 19, 11, 20, 18, 17, 16, 2),
                 quietHot  = c(16, 15, 17, 5, 10, 10, 15, 0),
                 loudCold  = c(16, 10, 10, 4, 3, 2, 14, 2),
                 quietCold = c(15, 8, 17, 8 ,10, 12, 5, 0))
```

As a tip for any future SO questions, please don't post *images* of data. Folks here need to be able to cut and paste the *text* of your data to test and verify solutions. Ideally, you should do this by the output of the `dput` function into a code block. People rarely go to the effort of manually transcribing data from your images.

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Lest approach your problem using `dplyr` an `tidyr` packages.

The first recommendation for you is to always add a minimal reproducible example of your data in order for us to use it and help you faster. This is not complicated, you can use the `dput(head(yourdata, 10))`, for example, or simulate some observations.

I did a simulation as follow:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  loudHot = sample(10:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
  quieHot = sample(10:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
  loudCold = sample(0:12, 5, replace = TRUE),
  quiteCold = sample(0:12, 5, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Now that we have the data, lest turn it to long format using `tidyr::pivot_longer`. This function recibe as argument the dataframe in wide format, de columns you want to gather (or those you do not want to gather using the `-` symbol).

```
# Data to long format
data_long <- pivot_longer(
  data, cols = -id, 
  names_to = 'variable', values_to = 'value'
  )
```

With that, now you only have to create the dummys, which is simple.

```
# Adding new variables
data_with_dummy <- mutate(
  data_long,
  volume = as.numeric(variable %in% c('loudHot', "loudCold")),
  temp = as.numeric(variable %in% c('loudHot', "quietCold"))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R approach:

```
# Original data
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 16),
  loudHot = c(14, 19, 11, 20, 18, 17, 16, 2),
  quietHot = c(16, 15, 17, 5, 10, 10, 15, 0),
  loudCold = c(16, 10, 10, 4, 3, 2, 14, 2),
  quietCold = c(15, 8, 17, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0)
)

# Stacked data
df_stacked <- stack(
  df,
  select = c(
    "loudHot", "quietHot", "loudCold", "quietCold"
  )
)

# New variable for volume
df_stacked$Volume <- as.numeric(grepl("loud", df_stacked$ind))

# New variable for Temp
df_stacked$Temp <- as.numeric(grepl("Hot", df_stacked$ind))

# Replace "ind" values with "ID"
df_stacked$ind <- rep(df$ID, times = 4)

# Reorder columns
new_df <- df_stacked[,c(2:4,1)]

# Rename columns
colnames(new_df) <- c("ID", "Volume", "Temp", "Value")

# Order by ID
new_df[order(new_df$ID),]
```

I believe your columns for "Volume" and "Temp" should be alternating sequences:

[image: Result of R Code]